# React-native Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

Tags: node.js, react-native

When I'm creating a new react-native app, then trying to run it on android emulateur, I'm getting this error. I tried all the solutions offered on google but without success... I followed all the documentation and started all over again several times but still this problem.Here are the screenshots of my info :

[image: Variables]

[image: Variables]

[image: SDK]

[image: SDK]

[image: Versions]

[image: The error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ! (Windows)

Steps one : Go to C:\Users\yourname.gradle and delete all folders.

Step two : Check that the anti virus is not in silent mode (very important)

Step tree : Create your new project : npx react-native init myAwesomeProject and authorize every file catch by the anti virus ! Then it will work.

If still doesn't work, open in android studio the android folder of your project, let it build everything, start your project from a terminal and run the project from your android studio application.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).